# Ethernet Web Server on Arduino with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, webserver, ethernet, arduino-uno, texas-instruments

I don't have much knowledge about web page designing and java scripting. I have used the Ethernet Web server example to control IOs from a client pc, however I would like to know if it is possible to update the data values automatically on a web page stored in the web server without sending a request from the client, for eg. to monitor values in the webserver on the Arduino continuously on a client PC without refreshing the web browser or sending a request using a button on the web page.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain more. In most cases it is very wrong for the server to talk to the client, without request. Although, web games(in the browser) are doing exactly this. Still in order to upgrade you need to refresh to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Ajax** to transfer data values between the Arduino web server and client browser. This happens in the background so you don't have to manually refresh the web page or click a button to update the data. A request has to be sent from the client (web browser) to the Arduino, but is invisible to the user.

Take a look at this web server tutorial:
http://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/

And pay attention to the sections on Ajax, particularly using Ajax with XML:
http://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/SD-card-AJAX-XML-web-server/

Comment: Thanks for the help Embinf . I will go through the links.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to exchange data between Arduino and the web browser.

Instead of using Ajax, you can use Websocket. With Websocket, the server (Arduino) can send data to web browser anytime without waiting for a request from the web browser.

To do so, you need to use a shield, called PHPoC Shield instead of Ethernet Shield. You can refer to some examples here:

- https://www.hackster.io/khanhhs/arduino-web-based-thermometer-a38752
- https://www.hackster.io/phpoc_man/arduino-dynamic-web-control-8da805